# how to set port forwarding on a cisco 881 router (with cisco configuration professional)

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I recently got a Cisco 881 router for work and I have everything working except port forwarding.

I want to forward all incoming port 80 requests to 10.10.10.60 
and all incoming port 53322 requests to 10.10.10.40

I am using cisco configuration professional and im not sure where to find this option.

Answer (score 1):

It should be under the "NAT" tab. You may refer to [Cisco CP End User Guides](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9422/products_user_guide_list.html) for more information on how to do it. Look especially under page 20-1 (of Cisco CP 2.0 End User Guide) Advanced NAT section - it should be your starting point.